# How to recursively move all folders one directory up back one directory

Tags: macos, terminal, file-transfer

I have folders in scenery/terrain that contain folders called terrain and objects. These folders have folders with data files. How do I move all of the contents scenery/terrain/[name]/terrain to scenery/terrain, and the contents of scenery/terrain/[name]/objects to scenery/objects?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no recursive option for the `mv` command, so if there are directories inside the directories you want to move, you'll have to use `cp`. How about this one:

```
cp -R scenery/terrain/*/terrain/* scenery/terrain/
cp -R scenery/terrain/*/objects/* scenery/objects/
```

Then when you're sure that worked:

```
rm -rf scenery/terrain/*/terrain
rm -rf scenery/terrain/*/objects
```

Comment: Good point, but I think under Mac OS it will be cp -R (upper case R).

Comment: @QSQ Thanks for the correction. Fixed it now.

Comment: -r worked fine.

Comment: WTF are you guys talking about? `mv my-app dev/my-app` will recursively move all content of `my-app` to the `dev/my-app`. Which means `mv` is recursive by default.

Answer (score 1):

```
mv scenery/terrain/*/terrain/* scenery/terrain/
mv scenery/terrain/*/objects/* scenery/objects/
```

Comment: Try it on a copy of the folder in case I misunderstood something :-)

Comment: Too late now.. Fail on my part. I can always just re-torrent the 13 GB   of scenery.

Comment: Didn't work. Says that "directory is not empty"

Comment: Hmm odd. I had tried it here with building a tree like that and putting files into scenery/terrain/a/terrain/  scenery/terrain/b/terrain/ and scenery/terrain/a/objects/ and scenery/terrain/b/objects/

Comment: Maybe I can try to move the current /terrain dir somewhere else to prevent file conflicts?

Comment: Are there directories inside scenery/terrain/*/objects/ or terrain/? It would complain if the directory is not empty if it contained a directory. Try replacing `mv` with `cp -r`. You can delete the originals later.

Comment: Ok. Will try...  It does  contain dirs.

Comment: A bit more explanation of the answer would be useful here. Explaining why it should work might help @AndrewD. work out why it didn't in his case.

Comment: What did work was cp -r, because the directories contained directories, meaning mv didn't like it. cp -r did.